Finding solutions to a complex integral equation
I would like to determine whether there exists some (holomorphic) function $f:\mathbb{C}\to
\mathbb{C}$ such that the following integral equation
$$
f\left( z \right) =\frac{C}{\left| z-z_0 \right|^{\alpha}}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha \theta}f\left( z+\left| z-z_0 \right|e^{\mathrm{i}\theta} \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}
$$
holds. Here $C$ is a constant, $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ is a given complex number and $\alpha>0$.
My attempt: I tried whether
$$
f\left( z \right) =\left( z-z_0 \right) ^{\beta}
$$
satisfies the equation for some $\beta$. Then I ended up with the equivalent condition
$$
\frac{C\left| z-z_0 \right|^{\beta}}{\left| z-z_0 \right|^{\alpha}}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha \theta}\left( e^{\mathrm{i}\theta}+\frac{z-z_0}{\left| z-z_0 \right|} \right) ^{\beta}\mathrm{d}\theta}=\left( z-z_0 \right) ^{\beta}
$$
and I'm not sure whether this is true for some $\beta$.
I also tried to define a sequence of complex functions: choose $f_0\in H(\mathbb{C})$ arbitrarily. Then define
$$
f_n\left( z \right) =\frac{C}{\left| z-z_0 \right|^{\alpha}}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha \theta}f_{n-1}\left( z+\left| z-z_0 \right|e^{\mathrm{i}\theta} \right) \mathrm{d}\theta},
$$
which gives a family of complex functions $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 0}$. However I don't see the sequence converges.
Can someone help me out? Any advice is welcomed.
Edit: I'm adding some background content. Indeed, this problem concerns the generalization of $n$-th derivative into arbitary fractional $p$-th order derivative. It is known to us that the $n$-th derivative for a holomorphic function is
$$
f^{\left( n \right)}\left( z \right) =\frac{n!}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\gamma}{\frac{f\left( \zeta \right)}{\left( \zeta -z \right) ^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}\zeta}.
$$
Therefore we may would like to define its $p$-th derivative:
$$
f^{\left( p \right)}\left( z \right) =\frac{\Gamma \left( p+1 \right)}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\gamma}{\frac{f\left( \zeta \right)}{\left( \zeta -z \right) ^{p+1}}\mathrm{d}\zeta},\hspace{0.5em}p\in \mathbb{Q} _+.
$$
To handle the multiple value problem arose in this definition, we cut out a line from $z$ to $z_0$ in the complex plane, here $z_0$ is arbitrarily chosen. Such a derivative defined is denoted $D_{z_0}^{p}f\left( z \right)$.
(For further details, see Anatoly A. Kilbas, Oleg Marichev, and Stefan Grigorievich Samko: Fractional Integrals and Derivatives Pp.421.)
Now we have (According to the preceding book, Theorem 22.1)
$$
D_{z_0}^{\alpha}f\left( z \right) =\frac{\Gamma \left( 1+\alpha \right)}{2\pi \left| z-z_0 \right|^{\alpha}}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha \theta}f\left( z+\left| z-z_0 \right|e^{\mathrm{i}\theta} \right) \mathrm{d}\theta}.
$$
I'm interested in the existence (nontrivial, of course) of a solution to the "fractional differential equations":
$$
\begin{cases}
 D_{z_0}^{\alpha}f\left( z \right) =Af\left( z \right) ,\\
 f\left( z_0 \right) =w,\\
\end{cases}
$$
which I ended up with my preceding problem on the existence of a function satisfying the integral equality.
Edit again:
I started to believe that finding a holomorphic solution to such an equation is very complicated. So I'm asking less, as mentioned in one of the current answer here, if $\alpha$ is an integer and
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(z-z_0)^n
$$
is a holomorphic solution to the integral equation, then we have
$$
f_{n+\alpha}\cdot\binom{n+\alpha}{n}=f_n.
$$
What if we try to define a reasonable weak solution (not necessarily holomorphic, or holomorphic functions that in some sense best satisfy the integral equation) to this integral equation?

what is the context for this as the problem really looks weird in the holomorphic context?

I have added some more details. Please check.

Is this the Riemann–Liouville fractional derivative? Maybe you can add that information. I don't have access to this book you cite.

As $f$ is holomorphic, we can expand it in a taylor series around the point $z_0$
\begin{align}
     f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n (z - z_0)^n.
\end{align}
Substituting this series into the condition you would like to satisfy gives (assuming you can integrate the series term by term)
\begin{align}
     \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n (z - z_0)^n &= \frac{C}{|z - z_0|^\alpha}\sum_n f_n (z - z_0)^n\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\alpha\theta}\left(1 + \frac{|z - z_0|}{z - z_0}e^{i\theta}\right)^n\mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align}
Expanding the bracket in the integral using the binomial theorem and performing the integration gives
\begin{align}
     \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n (z - z_0)^n &= C\sum_{nm}\binom{n}{m}  f_n (z - z_0)^{n-m}|z - z_0|^{m - \alpha}\int^{2\pi}_0 e^{i(m-\alpha)\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
%
     &= C\sum_{nm}\binom{n}{m}  f_n (z - z_0)^{n-m}|z - z_0|^{m - \alpha}\frac{e^{2\pi i(m-\alpha)} - 1}{i(m-\alpha)}.
\end{align}
I think that if $\alpha$ is not a positive integer, then the right hand side of the above equation is not holomorphic. This is because the absolute value funciton is not analytic. Hence, for non-integer $\alpha$, I don't think that there is any such holomorphic function which satisfies your equation.
As a sanity check, we can check what happens when $\alpha$ is an integer, as we know that there must be holomorphic solutions in this case. Now, when $\alpha$ is an integer, the integral over the complex exponential is only non-zero when $m=\alpha$. When $m=\alpha$ the integral is equal to $2\pi$. Therefore, the double sum reduces down to the following single summation
\begin{align}
     \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n (z - z_0)^n &= 2\pi C\sum_{n=\alpha}\binom{n}{\alpha}  f_n (z - z_0)^{n-\alpha}\\
%
     &= 2\pi C\sum_{n=0}\binom{\alpha + n}{\alpha}  f_{\alpha + n} (z - z_0)^{n}.
\end{align}
Equating the series term by term gives $C = 1/(2\pi)$ and a recursive formula for the coefficients $f_n$
\begin{align}
     f_{\alpha + n} = \frac{f_n}{\binom{\alpha + n}{\alpha}}.
\end{align}
In particular, if $\alpha=1$, then the solution to the above recursion tells us that $f(z)$ must be a multiple of the exponential function, as expected.

Thanks a lot for your answer. Your check when $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ gives me some new ideas. However this answer is not very "satisfying" to me (see edit again if you are willing to) so I'm upvoting this answer instead of accepting it.

I suppose if you wanted a non-holomorphic solution, something similar to this could work if you tried an expansion of the form $f(z, z^) = \sum_{nm=-\infty}^\infty f_{nm}(z - z_0)^n(z^ - z_0^*)^m$.
